# Implementing Matlab structure in python in a flexible way

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, defaultdict

I want to implement a structure as flexible as Matlab struct in python.
I have looked at [Matlab structure in Python [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23611197/matlab-structure-in-python) but the difference is I want a flexible structure where the field names and the depth of the structure are not know in advance.
So for example in Matlab you can say:

```
parent.child1.grandchild1=2
parent.child1.grandchild2=3
parent.child2.grandchild1.grand-grandchild1=1
```

without initializing thet struct with the field names.
I want to implement a structure that can be called whenever a user (who is not used to python) wants to store the value of a measurement in the structure he is using. So the call can happen multiple times in a code.
I have looked at nested defaultdicts but did not really find a solution.
I have read that numpy array are normally used for this purpose, but how can I constantly add fields to a numpy array without loosing performance?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally MATLAB only had 2d `matrices`.  Those are similar to `numpy.ndarray`.  Actually `numpy.matrix` is a subclass that is always 2d, meant for wayward MATLAB programmers.

MATLAB then added `cell`, which are somewhat like python `list`.  That is they can hold references to any kind of object.

Then it added `struct`.  That's somewhat like the python classes.  A class normally should have all attributes defined at the start, but it is often possible to add an attribute simply by assignment

```
anObject.foobar = "astring"
```

It went on to add a class system, first as a crude add on to `struct`, and then a bit more refined.  But in contrast, in python everything is an object, an instance of some class.

`scipy.io.loadmat` can read MATLAB .mat files (up to something like version 7.3).  It returns a `numpy` array - with object dtype for `cell`, and `structured` arrays for `struct`.  But none of those have the kind of extensibility that you see in MATLAB.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is good to know that there is no out-of-the-box solution and that I should implement it myself.